# Authentication Failed after an AEM 6.3 upgrade

Tags: aem

I am doing upgrade from AEM 6.1 author with mongodb to AEM 6.3 author.
 1. Pre upgrade task is done
 2. Replaced AEM 6.1 jar with AEM 6.3 jar alone parallel AEM 6.1 crx instance
 3. Unpacked AEM 6.3 jar with runmode mongo and it shows

```
  Build number changed, running in upgrade mode
  UpgradeUtil.handleInstallAndUpgrade has mode UPGRADE
```

4. Started the AEM 6.3 jar

Instance started with upgrade mode. Finally, its got started but not able to login. The below error is throwing.

11.11.2017 18:25:23.190 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1510404923182] GET /libs/granite/core/content/login.html HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.auth.impl.LoginSelectorHandler requestCredentials: Abort login due to apparent misconfiguration.

> 11.11.2017 18:25:23.190 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1510404923182] GET /libs/granite/core/content/login.html HTTP/1.1]
>   com.day.cq.auth.impl.LoginSelectorHandler requestCredentials: Possible
>   reasons: login page not existing or not accessible
>
> 11.11.2017 18:25:23.592 *ERROR* [qtp316797819-2676] com.day.crx.delite.impl.servlets.InitServlet Error while retrieving
>   infos java.lang.NullPointerException: null    at
>   com.day.crx.delite.impl.servlets.InitServlet.getFormattedName(InitServlet.java:126)
>   at
>   com.day.crx.delite.impl.servlets.InitServlet.doService(InitServlet.java:84)
>       at com.day.crx.delite.impl.AbstractServlet.service(AbstractServlet.java:52)
>       at com.day.crx.delite.impl.MainServlet.doService(MainServlet.java:129)
>       at com.day.crx.delite.impl.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:107)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:85)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.jav
>   a:79)
>       at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.jav
>   a:74)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:96)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.jav
>   a:74)
>       at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:295)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.jav
>   a:74)
>       at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:138)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
>       at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.jav
>   a:74)